# I have this message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined in React"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to have a main page that displays a list of four accommodations, with the ability to jump to a specific page per accommodation with a click.

I don't see where the error comes from.

My code produces

> Uncaught TypeError with a message of "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

#### APP.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import AccommodationList from './components/AccommodationList';
import AccommodationDetails from './components/AccommodationDetails';
//import accommodationsData from './data/accommodations.json';
import './styles/accommodations.css';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<AccommodationList/>}/>
                <Route path="/accommodation/:id" element={<AccommodationDetails/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

#### ACCOMMODATIONDETAILS.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import accommodationsData from '../data/accommodations.json';
import '../styles/accommodations.css';

function AccommodationDetails(props) {
    const accommodation = accommodationsData.find((a) => a.id === props.match.params.id);

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{accommodation.title}</h2>
        <p>{accommodation.description}</p>
        <p>Prix : {accommodation.price}€</p>
        <img src={accommodation.imageURL} alt={accommodation.altTxt} />
      </div>
    );
  }

export default AccommodationDetails;
```

#### ACCOMMODATIONLIST.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import allaccommodations from '../data/accommodations.json';
import '../styles/accommodations.css';

export default function AccommodationList(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1>Chez Nestor</h1>
                <AccommodationList allaccommodations={allaccommodations} />
            </div>
            <div className='container'>
                {props.allaccommodations.map(accommodation => (
                    <div key={accommodation.id}>
                        <figure>
                            <img src={accommodation.imageURL} alt={accommodation.altTxt} />
                            <figcaption>
                                <h2>{accommodation.title}</h2>
                                <p>{accommodation.description}</p>
                                <p>Prix : {accommodation.price}€</p>
                                <Link to={`/accommodation/${accommodation.id}`}>Voir plus</Link>
                            </figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

console.log(allaccommodations)
```

I tried changing names, or the term 'element' by 'component'. Where does this error come from, and how can I fix it?

Comment: It means that `props.allaccommodations` is undefined; What's supposed to be in that variable and what's *actually* in that variable?

Comment: however this property does give a table with the information sought such as the title, description and price of the accommodation (see attached screenshot)

Comment: The root `AccommodationList` used in your `Route` has no `allaccommodations` prop so it shouldn't be a surprise that it is undefined. This structure you're using looks like it will be infinitely recursive. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: No its why I asked this question, I'm not sure at all. What should I change to make it work ?

Comment: Well is it meant to be recursive or not? If not, why does `AccommodationList` try to render `AccommodationList`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  it is duplicate of many questions acessing undefined value.

Comment: @snnsnn That's not how questions get closed as duplicates. There's a specific VTC reason that includes linking a suitable duplicate target.

Comment: @Phil No I don't want this to be recursive.. It's the problem

Comment: You didn't answer my second question... why does `AccommodationList` try to render `AccommodationList`

Comment: I'm just trying to understand my mistake, especially through your remark, should I remove the AccommodationList route?

Comment: Are those file names actually capitalised? We have ***plenty*** *of* **formatting** ***`options`*** **on** `this` ***platform*** (though they shouldn't be overused).  There isn't ***any*** need to capitalise for emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

The issue starts in `AccommodationList`  where no props are passed to the component, so `props.allaccommodations` is undefined.

You also appear to be recursively rendering the `<AccommodationList />` component, which seems incorrect and unnecessary. It can likely be removed.

Assuming you want to render the imported `allaccommodations` it won't be located on the `props` object, it should be mapped directly.

Example:

```
<Route path="/" element={<AccommodationList />} /> // <-- no passed props
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import allaccommodations from '../data/accommodations.json'; // <-- imported here
import '../styles/accommodations.css';

export default function AccommodationList() { // <-- no props to reference
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Chez Nestor</h1>
      </div>
      <div className='container'>
        {allaccommodations.map(accommodation => ( // <-- referenced here
          <div key={accommodation.id}>
            <figure>
              <img src={accommodation.imageURL} alt={accommodation.altTxt} />
              <figcaption>
                <h2>{accommodation.title}</h2>
                <p>{accommodation.description}</p>
                <p>Prix : {accommodation.price}€</p>
                <Link to={`/accommodation/${accommodation.id}`}>
                  Voir plus
                </Link>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `props.allaccommodations` is defined with some value.
Then try using `map` on it.

Example:

```js
{
  props.allaccomodations &&
    props.allaccommodations.map((accommodation) => (
      <div key={accommodation.id}>
        <figure>
          <img src={accommodation.imageURL} alt={accommodation.altTxt} />
          <figcaption>
            <h2>{accommodation.title}</h2>
            <p>{accommodation.description}</p>
            <p>Prix : {accommodation.price}€</p>
            <Link to={`/accommodation/${accommodation.id}`}>Voir plus</Link>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    ));
}
```